# How to promisify and await for setImmediate in Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, async-await, setimmediate

I've been reading about how to not block Node's event loop. One way to avoid blocking is to use [partitioning](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/dont-block-the-event-loop/#partitioning).

I'm trying to use a partitioned loop in my code, but I cannot seem to await for my loop. Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
    const report = {
        someValue: 0
    };

    const runLoop = async () => {
        report.someValue += 1;

        // all sorts of async operations here that use async-await

        if (report.someValue < 1000) {
            await setImmediate(runLoop);
        }
    };

    await runLoop();
    console.log('Report is', report);
```

This returns "Report is { someValue: 1 }", but I'd want someValue to be 1000.

I'm guessing setImmediate doesn't return a promise, so I've tried promisifying it:

```
    const setImmediatePromise = util.promisify(setImmediate);

    const report = {
        someValue: 0
    };

    const runLoop = async () => {
        report.someValue += 1;

        // all sorts of async operations here that use async-await

        if (report.someValue < 1000) {
            await setImmediatePromise(runLoop);
        }
    };

    await runLoop();
    console.log('Report is', report);
```

But this also returns "Report is { someValue: 1 }".

So, how can I await for this recursive setImmediate "loop" so that I console.log report only after the entire recursion cycle is finished?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you have promisified `setImmediate`, you no longer pass a callback to it. Instead, you just `await` the promise it returns. Then afterwards you'd do the recursive call:

```
async function runLoop() {
    …
    if (…) {
        await setImmediatePromise();
        return runLoop();
    }
}
```

However, `async`/`await` gives you the capability to just write an actual loop:

```
const setImmediatePromise = util.promisify(setImmediate);

const report = {
    someValue: 0
};

while (report.someValue < 1000) {
    report.someValue += 1;
    // all sorts of synchronous operations here
    await setImmediatePromise();
}

console.log('Report is', report);
```

<sub>(Notice the slight difference to the recursion: the condition is already checked before the first iteration, and the `setImmediate` runs once more after the last iteration. Use `do`/`while` or even `while(true)`+`if(…)break;` if necessary.)</sub>

Btw, if you are already doing asynchronous (non-blocking) operations inside the loop, there is no reason to add an extra `setImmediate` to it. The [guide](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/dont-block-the-event-loop/#complex-calculations-without-blocking-the-event-loop) only deals with complex *synchronous* calculations that would *block* the event loop.

Comment: This seems to work, thanks! Did I understand correctly: In your example the `await setImmediatePromise();` that's inside the while loop makes that while loop non-blocking?

Comment: @iepure Yes. Make sure to understand [how the promisification works](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22519784/1048572). Try writing the same with `new Promise` instead of `util.promisify` (for practice only).